# Regexp that checks that there is no more slash

Tags: regex

I need a help with regular expression. I need to take only URLs with the next format:
'address.com/city[and then optional all symbols except slash]'

So, for example, the URL 'address.com/city/madrid?source=menu' is not appropriate.

I tried this option:

```
\.com\/.*[^\/]$
```

but it takes URLs like 'address.com/city/madrid?source=menu' and doesn't take only 'address.com/city/'

Comment: *In general*, you don't need to backslash-escape forward slashes, unless there's some containing syntax you're not telling us about (f/e, if you're working in the context of a different programming language that uses forward slashes to delimit regex boundaries).

Comment: and yes, your regex *does indeed* match `address.com/city/madrid?source=menu`. Why would you expect it not to?

Comment: From your example it sounds like you might want something a little bit like `^[^/]*[.]com/[^/]*/?$`, but it's hard to be certain. `.*` is pretty much always a bad idea in a context where you don't want it to do what it says on the tin (which is to say, to match *anything and everything*).

Comment: ...anyhow, it would be good to try to be more explicit in the question -- it's surprising to me that you want `address.com/city/` to match, even though it *does* have a trailing slash.

Comment: Also, please read (or reread) https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info -- some of the guidelines it gives, like telling us which variant of regex syntax, and/or which language or runtime you're using the regex you're trying to build in, are important. "Regular expression syntax" is not just one language, and the variants are not 100% compatible with each other.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
^address\.com\/city[^\/].*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You could match address.com/city followed by `[^\s/]*` matching 0+ times any char except a whitespace char or a forward slash.

```
^address\.com/city[^\s/]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VEgpr3/1)